# Styling an active link targeting an iframe

Tags: php, css, iframe, html-lists

I have this html code where links' target is an iframe.
So I want to add some style, highlighted links. I want to make the active link highlighted only with CSS( or/with php), I'm trying to avoid javascript.

Here is the code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenium" target="box">Rhenium</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tellurium" target="box">Tellurium</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin" target="box">Tin</a></li>
</ul>

<iframe name="box" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhenium"></iframe>
```

Best view: http://jsfiddle.net/WB8e8/

I've tried a lot of css tricks, including a non displayed iframe and combined it with different selectors (~ + >) with < li >, but it only goes messy and make css size big.
I've tried some php conditions too, I've couldn't manage to accomplish a result.
So, how to make this work? how to make a highlighted link when iframe displays content of the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not some JavaScript?

```
$(function() {
  $('ul li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WB8e8/2/)**

Comment: I guess because the original poster said "I'm trying to avoid javascript."

Comment: How to use this with php?

Comment: Well, since this example is using jQuery, you'd have to include a reference to jQuery in your page and then you'd also have to include this script either in `<script></script>` tags or reference that in a different file.  Just look up how to include JS in a PHP or HTML page.

Comment: That's not what I meant, sorry. How to convert it to  php instructions. i'm trying to avoid Javascript.

Comment: You can't use PHP to dynamically make changes in this way. If you want to use PHP you will have to reload the entire page and that kind of beats the point of having the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 attribute selector:

```
a[target="box"]:active {
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: I want it styled only when iframe is displaying the content

Comment: You will absolutely need to use JavaScript in order to set the state. CSS cannot do this.

Comment: that what i thought at first; it's like conditioning. how about php?

Comment: PHP would require a trip to the server and a page reload. You want to do this on the client using a click event to set a CSS class name on the active element. Eric's answer demonstrates what you need.

Comment: I assumed it would only load the Iframe, not the parent page. While you may be more comfortable with PHP, it's the wrong technique to use.

Comment: It is just useful when we clicked the link! Is there any method we can keep the changes until any other link is clicked?